# Firestore how to query field containing any of the values in the array

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Say my **Firestore** DB contains a collection of documents, each with a field that contains a large array of numbers. For Example:

```
{
arr: [11,13,24,16,37,50]
},
{
arr: [12,34,55,56]
},
{
arr: [12,16,27,59]
}
```

How can I make a query that returns all the documents where the 'arr' field contains any of the values in a certain array?

For example, if I query with [16,13] I get the first and third documents only (first one contains both 16 and 13, third one contains 16).

**Please note** that both the 'arr' array and the array in my query can **contain a large number of values** (> 1000), so I can't use '**array-contains-any**'.

Is it possible to do that?
Can I structure my DB differently in order to achieve that goal?

Comment: Which language are you intending to use to perform this?

Comment: Flutter, but it is mostly a Firebase/Firestore question

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `array-contains-any` support up to [10 comparison values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2). If you have a large array of over 1000 values, then you might be better to restructure your collection to something like this:

**Example:**

```
arr:
  arr_name:
    title: "arr_title"
        arr_1: {
            "10": true,
            "11": true,
            "12": true
        }
```

**Example:**

```
db.collection("arr_name")
    .whereField("arr_1.10", isEqualTo: true)
    .whereField("arr_1.12", isEqualTo: true)
```